# Failed to load Feature.FormsExtensions.Controllers.FieldBindingMapApiController

Tags: sitecore-forms, field

`ERROR [Sitecore Services]: Failed to load Feature.FormsExtensions.Controllers.FieldBindingMapApiController, Feature.FormsExtensions`

Does anyone know what this error means? I'm using Sitecore FormsExtensions version `sc10.1-4.0.2` on Sitecore 10.2. The documentation site for this extensions is offline. The source code only references `FieldBindingMapApiController` in the readme for version `1.4.1`

[Here is the repo for Sitecore Forms Extension](https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions)

[image]

Comment: usually, this error occurs if the controller is unable to present in the webroot. Please cross check if the latest dll is present in the webroot.

Comment: @SudheerSuggu best I can tell, it is the right version that comes with this version's download. I will include the image in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That must be an issue with upgrading from older version of `Sitecore.Forms.Extensions` to the newer version.

In `Sitecore.Forms.Extensions` for `Sitecore 9.0` there was a config file `App_Config/Include/Feature/FormsExtensions/Feature.FormsExtensions.ApiServices.config`. It referenced `Feature.FormsExtensions.Controllers.FieldBindingMapApiController` as `allowedController`.

That config file is no longer there in newer version at all. So if you upgraded, the file was never overwritten with new version of that file and it's still there, trying to use `FieldBindingMapApiController` which is not there in new dll.

Just remove `App_Config/Include/Feature/FormsExtensions/Feature.FormsExtensions.ApiServices.config` file.

Comment: Thank you Marek, we didn't clean up the configs properly. This answer was very helpful.